# ASUS G74sx - after BSOD, HDD & CD-Rom dissapears even from BIOS

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, bios, bsod

I have an ASUS G74sx DH-71 laptop.

*Prerequisites:*

1. HDD running in **AHCI mode**.
2. HDD S.M.A.R.T. **100% Health - Tested no bads, realocs or other issues**.
3. Ram Tested with memtest86+ **6 Cycles - No Issues**.
4. Operating system - **Windows 7 Ultimate x64**.

### Problem 1:

After a clean install I updated with windows update and now I'm receiving BSODs.

### Problem 2:

After BSOD, HDD & CD-Rom dissapears even from BIOS. Only after shutdown/restart  they appear again.

Measures I tryied to apply:

1. Play with various chipset drivers (**newest** vs **older** vs **ones from asus.com/support**)
2. Perform an stress test via AIDA64 for all components
3. Reinstall the system
4. Check current bios version - its the latest one installed

Observations:

1. It BSODs even when idle.
2. Mainly is an ntkrnlpa.exe (nt+0xDEE0C) 0xF4 error displayed

**I have uploaded the dumps using SF Diagnostic Tool [please take a look](http://www.filedropper.com/dumps_1).**

Comment: Can you put some of the information from the dump into the question itself?  So we can research that information and anyone with the same crash, can compare your notes, and verify any solution that eventually does work applies to them?  The linked file can stay for those brave enough to download a random file, but the question should be updated, so the relevant information is available to everyone.

Comment: @Ramhound Ok sure

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I've udpated the question

Comment: Cool, thanks for the updates.  Once thing that sticks out at me, is that if your 6 cycles of RAM testing took less than 48 hours, you didn't test the RAM long enough. aim fro 48-72hour STRAIGHT.  Even better: test one RAM module at a time for 48 hours (continuous) each, then test all the RAM for 48 hours (continuous). Seems like a ass-load of time, but over the years I've had plenty of potentially faulty RAM sticks not show errors until the third day of testing.  If the BSoDs are happening frequently enough it's probably faster to just get known-good replacement RAM and try it for a few days.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Hmm, I'll perform a thorough scan for each modules as you advice and come back with results. Thanks for your suggestion. If you have some other ideas please share I'll try those too.

Comment: I only suggest it be because you've done a lot of the basics, and what your presenting does seem like a potential memory issue.

Answer (score 1):

According to the dmp file, the  csrss.exe gets closed because of an IO Error:

```
(NTSTATUS) 0xc0000006 -   STATUS_IN_PAGE_ERROR                                           
# The instruction at 0x%p referenced memory at 0x%p. The
# required data was not placed into memory because of an I/O
# error status of 0x%x.
```

this causes your Windows to shut down.

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

CRITICAL_OBJECT_TERMINATION (f4)
A process or thread crucial to system operation has unexpectedly exited or been
terminated.
Several processes and threads are necessary for the operation of the
system; when they are terminated (for any reason), the system can no
longer function.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000003, Process
Arg2: 8739ad40, Terminating object
Arg3: 8739aeac, Process image file name
Arg4: 82e18f30, Explanatory message (ascii)

Debugging Details:
------------------

PROCESS_OBJECT: 8739ad40

IMAGE_NAME:  csrss.exe

PROCESS_NAME:  csrss.exe

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000006 - Die Anweisung bei "0x%p" verwies auf Speicher bei "0x%p". Die erforderlichen Daten wurden aufgrund eines E/A-Fehlers in "0x%x" nicht an den Arbeitsspeicher  bertragen.

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xF4_IOERR

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

STACK_TEXT:  
9a29eb9c 82ede96b 000000f4 00000003 8739ad40 nt!KeBugCheckEx+0x1e
9a29ebc0 82e5c06d 82e18f30 8739aeac 8739afb0 nt!PspCatchCriticalBreak+0x71
9a29ebf0 82e5bfb0 8739ad40 8692fa88 c0000006 nt!PspTerminateAllThreads+0x2d
9a29ec24 82c3d8c6 ffffffff c0000006 0180f40c nt!NtTerminateProcess+0x1a2
9a29ec24 772270f4 ffffffff c0000006 0180f40c nt!KiSystemServicePostCall
WARNING: Frame IP not in any known module. Following frames may be wrong.
0180f40c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 0x772270f4


FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0xF4_IOERR_IMAGE_csrss.exe

BUCKET_ID:  0xF4_IOERR_IMAGE_csrss.exe

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0xf4_ioerr_image_csrss.exe
```

check your HDD again with a different tool. Also replace the SATA cable.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I left my laptop at my local service center for a full diagnostics procedure. I think is an SATA Controller issue from the Intel HM65 Chipset, the fact that Both CD-ROM and HDD dissapear after BSOD is a non trivial situation. I'll post the results after the guys manage to identify the problem.Thank you again!